# Updating attribute table in several layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have dozens of layers in QGIS and all these layers have attribute field that I would like to update. I don't want to create new temporal layers with updated fields, rather just update the current layer attribute tables. And I wouldn't want to separately update each layer. I tried field calculator but it creates a new temporal layer. Is there any other solutions that could work? I'm using QGIS 3.22.

[image]

Comment: Using field calculator, you have an option to update existing fields. Field calculator does not create new layers, why do you think it does? Describe your workflow and add a screenshot to understand what's going on...

Comment: Field name is 'Modified' and I would need to update the field with a date when the layer have been updated. 

I'm not familiar with pyqgis but I'm afraid that I won't be able to use that as I would first need to be able to select the layers that have been modified in 1st of December and then update these layers with that date and then I would need to select layers that have been modified in 3rd of December and so on. The modification date is in the layer name.

Comment: I tried with field calculator and it created this 'calculated' temporal layer. How can I set the field calculator so that it does not create a temporal layer? Then I could run as a batch process and it probably could work for this.

Comment: Sorry, can you show a screenshot where filed calculator creates a new temporary layer? **My** field calculator does not! To update an existing field, check the box next to that, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaffO.png

Comment: make a selection by expression in which you select all the entities of 1 December .
Then in the field calculator: choose update of an existing field as suggested by @babel.

Comment: I added screenshot to my first message. Which version do you use? I noticed that in QGIS 3.4.3 there is option for updating an existing field, but unfortunately there is no option for running as a batch process, so probably is not solution for me in this case.

Comment: @LM10 if I use Select by expression, it only creates a selection in one vector layer? In my case there are several layers with the same date in the layer name and not sure how to include them all in the selection.

Comment: Ah, you use field calculator in batch mode - that was not clear to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use pyqgis with re (to find the date) and datetime (to format the date) modules.

The layers must have a 8 digit date somewhere in the layername, formatted like 20211221 (YYYYMMDD). Try it on a subset of layers and backup your data first.

```py
import re, datetime
fieldname = 'modified' #A string field that must exist in each table, change to match your fieldname

patt = r'\d{8}' #Search layername for 8 consecutive digits
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values(): #For each layer added to QGIS
    attrMap = {} #A dictionary to hold feature id: fieldindex:new value
    found = re.search(patt, layer.name()) #Find the 8 digits in a row
    fieldindex = layer.fields().indexFromName(fieldname) #Find the index of "modified" field
    if found:
        oldval = datetime.datetime.strptime(found.group(), '%Y%m%d') #datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 12, 0, 0) #Create a datetime object
        newval = datetime.datetime.strftime(oldval, '%m%d%Y') #Convert to a string in the format you want
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            attrMap[f.id()] = {fieldindex:newval}
        layer.dataProvider().changeAttributeValues(attrMap)
```

[image]